# IE Ajax not working properly, get different value between jQuery.Ajax and ashx browser result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, ashx

I have an Ajax call via JQuery.Ajax, Chrome and Firefox works fine. but for IE it is not working properly. Following screenshot is what I have in IE Debug:

[IE Debug http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/2301/capturerxa.png](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/2301/capturerxa.png)

On the right side the data shows the JSON value is ZERO.
However in IE I ping the url of Ashx with proper parameter, it shows correct result:

[Ashx result http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8079/capture2gu.png](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8079/capture2gu.png)

Can somebody tell what's error inside this?

Comment: One of those picture links is broken.

Comment: That adress on your nav bar is lower cased....in your ajax call looks capitalized(Systems/Job....blabla)

Comment: @RobertRozas, I think, in Windows it should not matter.

Comment: Maybe some caching problem? Did you disable caching for the ajax call?

Comment: @RobertRozas, However the JQuery returns a well format JSON, the call looks successful. And I checked getParameterByName('id') I get 10, which is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This make me think of a cache problem - happen often with IE and ajax. Could you give this a try (put it above your ajax call) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
</script>
```